# How to trigger azure mobile service sync on other clients?

Tags: push-notification, synchronization, signalr, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have a xamarin forms project that uses an azure mobile service with offline sync. The iOS client is working perfectly in that it can save things locally and sync in the background. The context of my app is a game scorekeeper. So, there are two players involved both scoring on the single device.

What I would like to happen is for the "visiting" player or the player who doesn't own the device in use (ie not the primary user) to have their device sync when new data is pushed from the device in use.

Device A pushes new content, Device B somehow knows to pull new content.

This could open the door for each player to score on their own devices in a future version.

Anyway, the question is how do I tell device B to pull? Do I use APN type notification and that triggers a sync, or SignalR to tell it to sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach on sync scenarios like this is to have your background sync process going at set intervals but then also trigger your sync process from a specific Push Notification.

If you send a Push Notification with a "special" payload (i.e. meaning something that just means to sync to your code). Then start the sync once the device receives that.

This article might help with Azure Push Notifications with Xamarin Forms: http://www.xamarinhelp.com/push-notifications/

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info. That's what I was thinking but I just wanted some input from someone who has experience before I went down that path.

Comment: Just adding that if its a game that relies on real time info you would want to go down the open connection to a server pushing down updates all the time. But if the background sync and occasional push notification to trigger is good enough for the sync frequency then its a good approach. Just remember push notifications are not guaranteed to reach the end device.

Comment: So, one last thing, how do we go about testing the push messages? Are there tools you would suggest? and am I correct in you can't use the iOS simulator to test, it needs to be on a physical device?

Comment: yes you are correct about the iOS simulator. There aren't any tools I am aware of to test, I have always tested on a demo Azure account.